# Windows 2008 setup IIS for all server users

Tags: windows, iis

It is a first time I am setting up server, so sorry for stupid questions.
I am trying to setup IIS on Windows 2008. Turning off Enhanced Security Configuration allowing me to go to default site, but only for me. Other user still can’t go there. What do I need to create and how to set it up, so anybody who get to the server, will have the same internet settings?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to give anon permission to the site try this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770966(v=ws.10).aspx